# My iPod Touch 2nd generation is dead

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

My iPod touch does not respond since yesterday. I cannot see anything on the screen and the buttons don't do anything, no backlighting either. The problem started when I wanted to plug my iPod into the wall to charge it (it was almost empty). When I plugged in my iPod, the screen went out and I have had no response since. I think the battery is broken, but I am not sure. How can I fix this? Or should I contact Apple?

Comment: I won't even bother contacting Apple. A replacement looks necessary here, and it is expensive as hell. Get a new one. If it's a battery problem, you might be able to replace battery by yourself then. But not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there a good possibility of it being a hardware issue, in which case you should contact Apple.

If you haven't already, about the only thing to do, is plug it into your computer for about 15 minutes. Sometimes it takes awhile, if the battery is completely dead, to get the charge started. But, I'm pretty confident that won't work, considering it had life before you plugged it in. It would be something to try if you wanted to take the time.

Comment: I have done this for days, also with a wall charger, no response whatsoever :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you had some sort of AC power surge. You should, indeed, contact Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging it into a tested power supply and holding down the home button and the sleep/wake button at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Contacting Apple is the best course of action here; however, you may not get support. It's a second-gen iPod touch, which means that it likely isn't covered by a warranty.

Comment: Actually, he will get support. But replacing it will be as expensive as a new one back in I think 2008? Buy a new one if replacement is necessary.